# using streamreader to edit between html tags

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to use streamreader to find all the lines that match  tags and then edit the content inbetween them?

So far i can read all the content of the html file into a rich text box, but i would prefer for it to find each line that has an h4 tag and load it into textbox1, 2 ,3 etc.

how would i do this? 
Could you please give an example, i am new to this.

```
    private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog dlgOpen = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            try
            {
                // Available file extensions
                dlgOpen.Filter = "All files(*.*)|*.*";
                // Initial directory
                dlgOpen.InitialDirectory = "L";
                // OpenFileDialog title
                dlgOpen.Title = "Open";
                // Show OpenFileDialog box
                if (dlgOpen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    // new StreamReader
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dlgOpen.FileName, Encoding.Default);
                    // Get all text from the file
                    string str = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    // CloseStreamReader
                    sr.Close();
                    // Show text
                    richTextBox1.Text = str;

                }

            }
```

Comment: You should use HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: ok could you give an example of how to use it with html agility pack then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `You should use HtmlAgilityPack`. and `could you give an example of how to use it with html agility pack then?`

Follow [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack).

You can find examples as well.[Here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)

Please do not try to use Regular Expressions to find and replcase. Because this great answer [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) begs to avoid that. I was told about it in comments

However I had used them 100% successfully with 110% limited scope. Limited mean my e.g. I have no other tags between any `<td> sometext </td>` and I wanted to replace all of them with `<td> sometext and some newtext </td>` and I had done it successfully. But I was 100% sure what number of tags and what maximum depth I had in my HTML with no `Unexpected` and `Irregular` behavior. If you have such limited and well defined HTML then [These Regular Expressions](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/all_about_html_tags.htm) might help.

Comment: Except that HTML is not a regular language, so Regular Expressions should not be used with it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders `<td> foo </td><td> bar </td>` can it not be changed to `<td> td </td><td> td</td>` using Regex.Replcae ? I mean tags can be searched using regular expressions and their contents(text) can be changed this way. Is there any rpoblem